# Multiple connections updating solr documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I am designing a web application where multiple connections make changes to a databse and solr 5 using two-phase commit. My questions is, is there a way to isolate the changes each connection make so that changes made by a connection will not be visible to the rest of connections until the changes have been successfully committed to the database and solr?

After numerous searches I read this interesting [article](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/) it suggests it is not possible. Anyone has done something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Solr's commit is server side to expose all accumulated documents to date.

One alternative approach you could use is to index into separate collections and then make them all available together as a single multi-collection alias. This, of course, implies that no document could theoretically exist in two collections at once (or you will get duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Solr provides **2 ways** of commits.

**Hard Commit** - It commits your documents into disk after given period of time.

**Soft Commit**  - It is real time commits your documents. It is good to use it. If you want to commits your document in real time.

You can config you **solrconfig.xml** such as

**Hard Commit** - It will properly commit your documents to disk within interval of 15 seconds.

```
 <autoCommit> 
   <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
   <openSearcher>true</openSearcher>
 </autoCommit>
```

**Soft Commit** - It will commit your documents in **real-time** whenever any commit happens.

```
<autoSoftCommit>
    <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```